# Breaking down instances of classes into lists, or: a better way to sum class variables?

Tags: python, class

This is part of a project that I've been working on for a bit now. I'm having a hard time synthesizing the mental pseudocode with something I can actually write, largely due to personal misconceptions about how stuff works.

I'm tracking inventory for an imaginary fruit stand, using the following class:

```
class Fruit(object)
    def __init__(self,name,qty,price)
        self.color = str(color)
        self.qty = int(qty)
        self.price = float(price)

    def getName(self): return self.color
    def getQty(self): return self.qty
    def getPrice(self): return self.price
    def description(self): return self.color,self.qty,self.price
```

Objects in this class end up getting imported as values for keys of a dictionary. There can be multiple values for each key, stored in a list, such that when the dictionary is printed, it returns something like this (with line breaks for readability:)

```
Lemon: [(Yellow, 5, 2.99)]
Apple: [(Red, 10, 0.99), (Green, 9, 0.69)]
Cherry: [(White, 2, 5.99),(Red, 5, 5.99)]
```

I am trying now to end up getting the sum value of all bits of fruit on my imaginary fruit stand. My original thought was just to treat each value as a list, iterate through the list until I hit an integer, multiply the integer by the float in the index right behind it, and then add that quantity to a variable that had a running total; then move on to keep looking for another integer. Which would work great, if "index 1" of list "Cherry" weren't (Red, 5, 5.99) rather than (2).

So, a couple of questions.

1. Every time I do something like this, where I have a dictonary with multiple values which are all class objects, each value is stored as a parenthetical (for lack of a better thing to call it.) Is that something that should be happening, or do I need to re-evaluate the way I am doing what I am doing, because I am causing that to happen?
2. If I don't need to re-evaluate my choices here, is there a way to break down the "parentheticals" (for lack of a better thing to call them immediately coming to mind) to be able to treat the whole thing as a list?
3. Is there a better way to do what I want to do that doesn't involve iterating through a list?

Thanks in advance. I have been fighting with various parts of this problem for a week.

Comment: Incidentally, what you're called a parenthetical is called a tuple ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming a dictionary like this:

```
fruit_stand = {
    "Lemon": [(Yellow, 5, 2.99)],
    "Apple": [(Red, 10, 0.99), (Green, 9, 0.69)],
    "Cherry": [(White, 2, 5.99),(Red, 5, 5.99)]
}
```

You can actually just iterate over the dictionary to get its keys:

```
for fruit_name in fruit_stand:
    print fruit_name

# Lemon
# Apple
# Cherry
# NOTE: Order not guaranteed
# Cherry, Lemon, Apple are equally likely
```

You can then use the `items` method of the dictionary to get a tuple (what you are calling a "parenthetical") of `key`, `value` pairs:

```
for fruit_name, fruits in fruit_stand.items():
    print fruit_name, "=>", fruits

# Lemon => [(Yellow, 5, 2.99)]
# Apple => [(Red, 10, 0.99), (Green, 9, 0.69)]
# Cherry => [(White, 2, 5.99),(Red, 5, 5.99)]
```

`list`s (that's the bracketed `[]`) are also iterable:

```
for fruit in [(White, 2, 5.99),(Red, 5, 5.99)]:
    print fruit

# (White, 2, 5.99)
# (Red, 5, 5.99)
```

So we can work with each `fruits` list to get access to our `tuple`:

```
for fruit_name, fruit_list in fruit_stand.items():
    # Ignore fruit_name and iterate over the fruits in fruit_list
    for fruit in fruit_list:
        print fruit
```

As we saw with `items` we can unpack tuples into multiple values:

```
x, y = (1, 2)
print x
print y
# 1
# 2
```

So we can unpack each `fruit` into its component parts:

```
for fruit_name, fruit_list in fruit_stand.items():
    # Ignore fruit_name and iterate over the fruits in fruit_list
    for color, quantity, cost in fruit_list:
        print color, quantity, cost
```

And then getting the total isn't hard:

```
# We need to store our value somewhere
total_value = 0
for fruit_name, fruit_list in fruit_stand.items():
    # Ignore fruit_name and iterate over the fruits in fruit_list
    for color, quantity, cost in fruit_list:
        total_value += (quantity * cost)

print total_value
```

---

All that being said, there are *much* clearer ways of doing things:

1. You could use list comprehension to simplify your `for` loops:

   ```
   for fruit_name in fruit_stand
       operation(fruit_name)
   ```

   can be translated to this list comprehension:

   ```
   [operation(fruit_name) for fruit_name in fruit_stand]
   ```

   Therefore, we can translate our nested `for` loops into:

   ```
   sum([cost * quantity \  # Final operation goes in front
       for _, fruits in fruit_stand.items() \
           for _, cost, quantity in fruits])
   ```

   Because we don't actually *need* the list we can get rid of it and Python will create a generator for us instead:

   ```
   sum(cost * quantity \  # Note the missing []
       for _, fruits in fruit_stand.items() \
           for _, cost, quantity in fruits)
   ```
2. You could add a `__add__` method to `Fruit` so that adding two sets of fruits together gives you the total cost of both sets of `Fruit` (but you would probably want to create an intermediate data structure to do that, say `Basket` so `Fruit` didn't have to worry about `quantity` which doesn't really belong to `Fruit`, save in the sense that any instance of `Fruit` has the intrinsic quantity 1.  I'm omitting the code for this option because this answer is already far too long.

Comment: @JoelCornett - and now fixed.  Thanks for the catch - I've been up way too late!

Comment: @Sean Vieira, Thank you so much; I appreciate the step by step detail you went into on this. I do have one follow-up question as I explore this further. When unpacking into component parts ("for qty,cost in fruit_list") I got: "ValueError: too many values to unpack." Is there something I can do to avoid this?

Comment: @user2113818 - if there are *three* elements in each tuple in `fruit_list` but you only provide *two* variables then Python throws that error :-)  Change that line to `for color, qty, cost in fruit_list` and things will work.  (Or, since you are ignoring `color` you could use `_` instead to signify that you're ignoring it on purpose).

Comment: @SeanVieira, thank you. Unfortunately, I am still getting the same error ("too many values to unpack") with three elements included. Does this point to something stupid I've done elsewhere?

Comment: I just tested this code out to see if it works and indeed it does (tested in Python 2.7.) (I did have to put single quotes aroudn the color names when defining the fruit_stand dictionary but that was the only change I needed to make to make this run.)  Perhaps your dictionary doesn't look quite like the one you posted in your question?

Comment: @Qanthelas, that's entirely possible. I ended up just doing things a little bit differently for this project for the sake of getting it done, but I'm definitely going to experiment more with this for my own edification. Sean, again, I really appreciate the depth of your answer and the time you put into illustrating the step by step. That really helped me!

Answer (score 4):

The word you're looking for is ["tuple"](http://www.diveintopython.net/native_data_types/tuples.html). These "parentheticals" are [tuples](http://www.diveintopython.net/native_data_types/tuples.html).

One of Python's major strengths is its compact syntax for iterating over lists. You can calculate the sum of the prices of each fruit in a single line:

```
>>> fruit = [("Red", 10, 0.99), ("Green", 9, 0.69)]
>>> sum(qty * price for color, qty, price in fruit)
16.11
```

Breaking it down, the stuff inside of `sum()` is called a [generator expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/). `for color, qty, price in fruit` iterates over `fruit` and unpacks the tuples into three named variables. These variables can then be used on the left-hand side of the `for`. For each tuple in the `fruit` list, the generator expression calculates `qty * price`.

If you put this expression inside of square brackets it becomes a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and lets you see the calculated values.

```
>>> [qty * price for color, qty, price in fruit]
[9.9, 6.209999999999999]
```

Comment: Thank you- and thanks also for reminding me about the proper name for what I was calling a parenthetical. I've tried a few versions of this. I'm trying a few ways to define the list here, "fruit," by bringing in the list I want- most recently "for key in Fruit: values = Fruit.get(key) \n total = sum(qty * price for color, qty, price in fruit". This returned ValueError- too many values to unpack. Which means "something you are doing is stupid," but I'm not sure that I can think of a better way to bring in the values. Am I even on the right track with how I'm thinking about it?

Answer (score 1):

I would first ditch the `returnFoo` methods, as it's just shorter to type `apple.price`:

```
class Fruit(object)
    def __init__(self, name, qty, price)
        self.color = str(color)
        self.qty = int(qty)
        self.price = float(price)
```

If you aren't accepting arbitrary inputs like `qty='100'`, you don't need the type conversions either:

```
class Fruit(object)
    def __init__(self, name, qty, price)
        self.color = color
        self.qty = qty
        self.price = price
```

What you're left with is a class that does nothing but store values. In that case, I would just use a dictionary:

```
fruit = {
    'color': 'red',
    'qty': 1000,
    'price': 1.99
}
```

To add up the costs, you first need fruits:

```
fruits = [{
    'color': 'red',
    'qty': 1000,
    'price': 1.99
}, {
    'color': 'blue',
    'qty': 100,
    'price': 15.99
}, {
    'color': 'orange',
    'qty': 10,
    'price': 5.99
}]
```

And then you can use a `for` loop:

```
total = 0

for fruit in fruits:
    total += fruit['qty'] * fruit['price']
```

Which can be further simplified with `sum` and a generator expression:

```
total = sum(fruit['price'] * fruit['qty'] for fruit in fruits)
```

An alternative would be to use `FruitStand` class and your original `Fruit` class:

```
class FruitStand(object):
    def __init__(self, fruits=None):
        self.fruits = fruits or []

    def totalCost(self):
        return sum(fruit.price * fruit.qty for fruit in self.fruits)
```

Comment: thank you. Project specs mandate the use of a class for the fruits instead of just a dictionary, so I'm going with your second option. I tried to call this as (using ; for line breaks) "fruity = FruitStand ; total = fruity.totalCost() ; print total". What I'm getting is the error "unbound method totalCost() must be called with FruitStand instance as first argument." Is this telling me that I need to specify the value I want it called on, and if so, can you give me a hint as to how I would do that? (I did read some threads here that touched on it but am not sure I understand how to apply.)

Comment: @user2113818: `fruity = FruitSalad` sets `fruity` to the class `FruitSalad`. You need to initialize the class by doing `fruity = FruitSalad()` or `fruity = FruitSalad([list of fruits])`.

Comment: @Blender- thanks. The amendment now prints the following for total: "0 ; 0". Which I presume means that the FruitStand class isn't recognizing any fruit instances- is this correct? In order to get it to do so, do I have to involve the "class inheritance" that I encountered in reading some other materials for this project?

Comment: @user2113818: Not really. Do you add any fruit instances in? Something like `fruity.fruits.append(a_fruit_instnace)`?